# Chart sometimes exports to a blank .jpg file

Tags: excel, vba, export

This code exports the Range as .jpg to a location that is attached to an email with another module running this.

```
Sub Export_Dashboard_To_PC()
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant, pic As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Dashboard.jpg"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range(Sheets("BP").Range("AE4")).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        Set sht = Sheets.Add
        sht.Shapes.AddChart
        sht.Shapes.Item(1).Select
        Set objChart = ActiveChart

        With objChart
            .ChartArea.Height = Sheets("Dashboard").Range(Sheets("BP").Range("AE4")).Height
            .ChartArea.Width = Sheets("Dashboard").Range(Sheets("BP").Range("AE4")).Width
            .ChartArea.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            .Paste
            .Export Filename:=FName, FilterName:="jpg"
        End With

        sht.Delete
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Sheets("BP").Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It all happens in one and sometimes the code exports the image as a blank and attach it as a blank on the email and sends it. I can see the problem is at the export because when I go to the location of the export and open the .jpg, it shows a blank.

I have stepped through it many times, every time it works.

`DoEvents` gives me the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this kind of routine in my commercial Excel add-in, and I've had to overengineer the stuffing out of it. So I started with your code, cleaned it up a bit (it wouldn't compile with Option Explicit set), and inserted some lines to (a) try to make it work, and (b) figure out where it got hung up. Part of what I did was build the copy/paste into a loop, to get more feedback faster.

```
Sub Export_Dashboard_To_PC()
  ' turn these off for testing
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  ' fully qualify the ranges
  Set RangeToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard"). _
      Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BP").Range("AE4").Text)

  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
  'DoEvents ' sometimes needed after Worksheets.Add but apparently not this time

  Dim ImgNumber As Long
  For ImgNumber = 1 To 20
    Dim FName As String
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Dashboard" & ImgNumber & ".png"
    ' PNG much better image format than JPG for worksheet images (crisper, half the size)

    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = wks.Shapes.AddChart(, wks.Columns(ImgNumber).Left, wks.Rows(ImgNumber).Top).Chart
      ' inserted .left and .top so I could see individual charts
    'DoEvents ' sometimes needed after Shapes.AddChart but apparently not here
    With cht
      With .ChartArea
        .Height = RangeToCopy.Height
        .Width = RangeToCopy.Width
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
      End With
      DoEvents ' inserted because sometimes Range.CopyPicture throws an error
      RangeToCopy.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
        ' copy as bitmap here, more reliable, rather than convert to bitmap during export
      Dim iLoop As Long, MaxLoop As Long
      MaxLoop = 10
      For iLoop = 1 To MaxLoop
        DoEvents ' inserted b/c sometimes clipboard is slow to contain copied object
        .Paste
        If .Shapes.Count > 0 Then
          ' yay, image pasted into chart
          Debug.Print iLoop
          Exit For
        End If
        If iLoop >= MaxLoop Then
          ' boo, never succeeded
          MsgBox "Export Picture Failed", vbCritical
          GoTo ExitSub
        End If
      Next
      'DoEvents
      .Export Filename:=FName, FilterName:="png"
      'DoEvents
      '.Parent.Delete ' don't delete, examine after run
    End With
  Next

ExitSub:

  'wks.Delete ' don't delete, examine after run

  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BP").Activate

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

So what I learned was where I needed to put the `DoEvents`, and where the big bottleneck occurs. The big bottleneck is getting the range copied into the clipboard. VBA starts the copy, and sometimes the copy takes longer than VBA takes to get to the paste, and VBA isn't patient enough to wait. `DoEvents` is supposed to make VBA wait, but it doesn't always work that way. If the clipboard is still empty (doesn't yet contain a copy of the range), then nothing is pasted, and the exported chart is blank.

So I put another loop after the copy, and did the paste inside the loop. After the paste, if the chart contained an object, then the paste must have worked, so I proceeded to the export.

Usually (in 14 of 20 big loops) the paste resulted in a shape being added to the chart in the first small loop, but in 2/20, it took as many as 6 or 7 small loops.

So for the final code, this is what I came up with. I had to insert

```
Application.ScreenUpdating True
```

before the copy, otherwise the copied range was always blank (a blank shape was pasted into the chart.

```
Sub Export_Dashboard_To_PC()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  ' fully qualify the ranges
  Set RangeToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard"). _
      Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BP").Range("AE4").Text)

  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

  Dim FName As String
  FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Dashboard_" & Format(Now, "hhmmss") & ".png"
  ' PNG much better image format than JPG for worksheet images (crisper, half the size)

  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
  With cht
    With .Parent
      .Height = RangeToCopy.Height
      .Width = RangeToCopy.Width
    End With
    With .ChartArea
      .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
      .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' otherwise copied region blank
    DoEvents ' inserted because sometimes Range.CopyPicture throws an error
    RangeToCopy.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim iLoop As Long, MaxLoop As Long
    MaxLoop = 10
    For iLoop = 1 To MaxLoop
      DoEvents ' inserted b/c sometimes clipboard is slow to contain copied object
      .Paste
      If .Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        ' yay, image pasted into chart
        Exit For
      End If
      If iLoop >= MaxLoop Then
        ' never succeeded
        MsgBox "Export Picture Failed", vbCritical
        GoTo ExitSub
      End If
    Next
    .Export Filename:=FName, FilterName:="png"
  End With

ExitSub:

  wks.Delete

  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BP").Activate

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Follow Up**

In my production code (which I checked after posting this), I don't ever set

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

I also don't insert a new sheet, instead I put my temporary chart on the active sheet, which contains the range I'm exporting.

And my internal loop is

```
With .chart
  Do Until .Pictures.Count = 1
    DoEvents
    .Paste
  Loop
  .Export sExportName
End With
```

Same thing, except it assumes it will never never get into an infinite loop.

Comment: Just to add a comment almost 2 years later, I have tested this and it worked ever since. Thank you very much good sir

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when using VBA to paste an image into a chart object and export it as a jpg file.  I noticed there were no issues when I slowly stepped through the code line by line.  Additionally, there were no issues when I added a comment box after pasting the image but before exporting as a jpg, forcing the code to pause.  This led me to believe the problem was with Excel not having sufficient time to complete the paste procedure before exporting the image file.

I solved the issue by adding a 3-second loop between pasting and exporting. I also turned on Screen Updating.

```
Dim time1, time2
time1 = Now
time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")
    Do Until time1 >= time2
    DoEvents
    time1 = Now()
    Loop
```