# Referencing ActiveChart generates run-time error '91', "object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

The run-time error is shown at Activechart.SetSourceData. I'm not sure if its because I'm using the chart on so many worksheets. There are 11 sheets.

There is an active chart. It works if I go step by step, but if I execute it together it shows the error.

I tried setting a chartObject instead of ActiveChart but that doesn't work either.

```
Sub line1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "LIVE " Then        
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("$A$2:$A" & LastRow & ",$H$2:$H" & LastRow)
    End If

Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveChart`? You have `xChart`, work with that - `xChart.Chart.SetSourceData...`

Comment: It shows another error. "Object doesn't support this property"

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the revised line you are using.

Comment: Do you really want the whole row?

Comment: ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("$A$2:$A" & LastRow & ",$H$2:$H" & LastRow). This is fine too.

Comment: You don't appear to be following @BigBen's suggestion? `ActivateChart`??

Comment: This is what I'm currently using

Comment: "This". What? The code above is different to your original code and different to your comment. There is no `ActivateChart`. Please clarify in your question exact code you are using.

Comment: Sorry didnt see that, i edited it

Comment: `ActiveChart` is `Nothing`, so a member call against it will raise error 91. You need to `Activate` a chart object if you want to use `ActiveChart`... but then if you can `Activate` a chart object, then you might as wel just do `theChartObject.SetSourceData = ...`

Comment: I guess a chart is not active (not sure if that would cause your error). Either way the better approach would be the original one using a variable and referencing that.

Comment: There is an active chart. It works if I go step by step, but if i execute it together it shows the error. Is it because I'm using many worksheets?

Comment: Re: "There is an active chart. It works if I go step by step, but if i execute it together it shows the error. Is it because I'm using many worksheets?" - It is common that stepping through code succeeds as it slows processing so "Active" objects have time to become something. An example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222850/chart-sometimes-exports-to-a-blank-jpg-file